Bootstrap 5 scss build full import works but part by part import doesn't
I'm following the Bootstrap 5 customization docs and able to get a build working using "option A": include all of Bootstrap. However, almost nothing renders properly using "option B": pick the parts you need. I haven't added any customizations yet, just copy/pasted the 2 scss examples from the docs (code included below).
Option A:
// Custom.scss
// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap
// Include any default variable overrides here (though functions won't be available)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
// Then add additional custom code here

Here's a screenshot of my test page using this, where everything appears as expected:

And here's option B:
// Custom.scss
// Option B: Include parts of Bootstrap

// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets (including any separate color mode stylesheets)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";

// 4. Include any default map overrides here

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";

// 6. Optionally include any other parts as needed
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/helpers";

// 7. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

// 8. Add additional custom code here

With a screenshot of the results:

I'm building with the suggested sass --watch ./scss/custom.scss ./css/custom.css command. Is there anything I'm missing for "Option B" that's causing the styles to not build properly? It's the option "encouraged" by the docs so I'd like to go with it if possible.
